# Incremental column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table in Postgresql with serial Id. I created another table serial Id. Now I want to merge both tables. So I want to change the serial Id of second table starting from the last serial Id of first table.

Say first table has serial Id 126799. So serial Id of second table should start from 126800.
I have already processed my second table. Just want to change the serial Id.
Please suggest.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of the two tables and the result you want, please?

Comment: you want to merge two tables and insert into third table or you want to merge the second table table into first table(vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

To merge the rows from `table2` into `table1`, run

```
INSERT INTO table1 (/* all columns except "id" */)
SELECT /* all columns except "id" */ FROM table2;
```

Then `id` for the new rows will be generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if you wans to add table 2 in table one then simply skip column serial Id  of table 2 and insert into table 1 like below:

> insert into table1 (column name except serial Id) select (column name
> except serial Id ) from table 2.

Note: **Column name** and **number of columns** must be same in insert column( table 1) and select columns (table 2).

another if you want to merge in different table then, create table 3 with same definition and run below queries

> insert into table3 (column name except serial Id) select (column name
> except serial Id ) from table 1. insert into table3 (column name
> except serial Id) select (column name except serial Id ) from table 2.

serial Id will be generated automatically.